# How to code an image view to view another activity

Tags: android-studio

I am new to android studio, I want to make the images in my main activity show another activities when clicked, I tried many things but I can't get it to work. (I have only added 1 imageview but I will add four more). Thanks for your help. here is MainActivity.java

```
package com.wima.civilengineeringcalculator;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

here is content_main.XML (Which one is better to use android:clickable="true" or android:onClick="action1", in imageview)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="com.wima.civilengineeringcalculator.MainActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main"
>



<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="end">

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="@string/sma"
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:singleLine="false" />

        <ImageView
            android:onClick="onClickTest"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageView" android:src="@drawable/spr" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="AB"
            android:id="@+id/textView3" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"></TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"></TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"></TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

the target activity is SolMecAnalysis

```
package com.wima.civilengineeringcalculator;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.content.Intent;

public class SolMecAnalysis extends AppCompatActivity {

Intent intent = getIntent();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sol_mec_analysis);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton)        findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What your image view is doing with that xml is trying to execute the function called onClickTest which does not exist in your main activity also when your main activity starts it does not uses the "content_main.xml"

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

that says that the xml that you're watching in that activity is activity_main.xml,
also you should add in your main activity a void like this one:

```
 public void onClickTest(View view) {
     Intent i = new Intent(this, SolMecAnalysis.class);
     startActivity(i); 
     finish();

 }
```

that void will execute every time you click(tap) the image and start your other activity

To return to your Main activity add this code in SolMecAnalysis.class:

```
    @Override 
    public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(SolMecAnalysis.this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish(); 
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked, but now when I go to SolMecAnalysis in emulator and when I press the back button it doesnt go back to main activity it just closes the app, any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: Thanks a lot ivan, saved my day,

Comment: No problem, glad it helped.